# MySqli multiple queries how to handle result faster way

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have to INSERT thousand of records. 
I use `msqli::multi_query()` in a loop and want to 'multi_query' block of n query (where 'n' is a parameter). 
first INSERT goes ok, the second goes wrong because I have to manage result like this :

```
while($mysqli->more_results())
{
    $mysqli->next_result();

    if($res = $mysqli->store_result()) // added closing bracket
    {
        $res->free(); 
    }
}
```

The problem is that this chek is slow.

Question is : how can I optimize this bulk INSERT makeing faster the manage of result ?

Comment: What is the source of the thousands of records you must insert? And did you know you can perform multiple inserts with one statement?

Comment: `INSERT INTO table_name (field1, field2, fieldn) VALUES (data1,data2,datan), (data1,data2,datan);`

Comment: hi, @mclayin 
query are like this

 
`$sql = "INSERT delayed INTO dailystat (timestamp, id, value $campo1) values ($timestamp, $id, $value $value1) on duplicate key update value = if(value >= - $value,value + $value,0);";`

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting in a one table just use batch mod in INSERT.
Example:
`INSERT INTO TABLE (field1,field2,field3) VALUES (value1,value2,value3),(value4,value5,value6)`

Use `for` or `foreach` in php to make query and then simply use `mysqli_query`. Judging by errors you mentioned in comment section, you violating ket restrictions meaning you are trying to insert the same value twice.

If you are inserting in a different tables, you can use `multi_query` interface.
Prepare one query `Insert1;Insert2;`
And use multi_query like this

```
  $con->multi_query($query);
    while (mysqli_more_results($con)) {
        mysqli_use_result($con);
        mysqli_next_result($con);
    }
```

Comment: I use multi_query as you suggest me,
and build a block of 5000 sql string query into unique  $query string
but performance are not  good, so I would like what I can optimize
to be faster

`if ( $step > 5000 )
{     
       /* execute multi query */  
      if (  $mysqli->multi_query( $query )  === TRUE )
{
       f_log ( "New records (query) created successfully" , "credito.debug.log");
} else {
       f_log ( "Error (query): " .  $mysqli->error  , "credito.debug.log");
} 

while ($mysqli->more_results()) 
{
 $mysqli->use_result();
 $mysqli->next_result();
}
`

Comment: @AlessioGiuliano performance depends on numerous facts. Provide you table structure with information about indices .

Comment: I can't perform next multiple query until I fetch de result of the previous.
I execute this code to do that, but it take a lot of time
How can I do it quickly ?  
  
`while($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result()) {  
 $extraResult = $mysqli->use_result();  
 if($extraResult instanceof mysqli_result){  
 $extraResult->free();  
 }  
}`